# Xcode Interface Builder is showing "No selection" for all files

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

No matter what I've got selected in Interface Builder, the Inspector did apparently not register the selection and only showed "No selection".

I tried opening and closing files, restarting Xcode and even rebooting my Mac. No change! What the heck is going on?

Other projects work just fine. It's just this project...

Answer (score 134, accepted):

This was driving me crazy for a long time. I found nothing here on Stackoverflow about this, and not by googling either, initially.

Luckily, after googling a couple of different ways, I finally found the simple solution [here](http://embraceware.com/blog/2015/09/solution-for-no-selection-in-xcode-interface-builder).

Snipped from that site:

> Here’s how you can fix it in two steps without even having to restart
>   Xcode:
>
> - Select another file (which isn’t an Interface Builder type) in the    current tab with the issue.
> - Open a new tab and select the Interface Builder file which was having    the problem.

Shame on you, Apple!

Comment: This issue still occurs randomly even on XCode 9.4 and yet this solution still works haha! Cheers!

Comment: Still relevant in 2018, xcode 10. Many thanks! And yes like @Himan Dhawan said, shame on you Apple!

Comment: Had the same issue, selecting another file which is not IB type in the current tab solved.

Comment: Wow. Happened to me right now in 12.5.1. 
Cheers for the solution

Answer (score 24):

In Xcode 8.3, the preferred solution doesn't appear to work. My solution, similar to travdu, was to click the "Show the version editor" button (the two arrows pointing left and right), then back to the "Show the Standard editor". Doing that fixed it for me.

Comment: You save my life.

Comment: Fantastic that this bug still exists 

Comment: This is the one that fixed it for me !

Comment: Yeah, You can do it with any combination of these 3 icons :)

Comment: Still exists (for xcdatamodel anyway), this fix works, those above do not

Comment: It's 2021 and you just saved my life. I was going nuts because I couldn't open my xcodeproj file to edit my build settings, after updating Xcode. This did the trick. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 18):

**MOST SIMPLE SOLUTION:**

(For each of those who has tried all the above options like me, try this once):

1. Switch to the **LaunchScreen.storyboard** from your **Main.storyboard**
2. See if you can access all the Inspectors on right side in **LaunchScreen.storyboard** .

> if yes,

3. Switch back to  **Main.storyboard**

Always work for me! Hope this also help to someone. Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Above solution works for **xib only** projects too.

Comment: Worked for me on a xib only project too. I opened the LaunchView.xib

Answer (score 14):

There is also possibility in Xcode 7.3.1. to switch between "Standard editor" and "Assistant editor" in the upper right corner to "deal" with this bug.

[image: Click between first two icons]

Comment: The accepted answer usually helped me before. However today I saw this problem in a specific version of data model, this answer fixes the problem while the accepted one doesn't. XCode 9.2.

Answer (score 4):

**Very Simple Solution Work for me**

1- Open Any **ViewController**

2 **Command+T**, for New Tab

3- Open again storyBoard in that **New Tab**

**Then It will Work**

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in the new tab and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions don't work, try adding an object (e.g a label) onto the main storyboard. Brought all the inspectors back for me with Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced that the "Utility Area doesn't display anything" symptom, with Xcode version 9.0. Thanks for the tips! In my case, after I closed all the files displayed in the Assistant Editor, you would think it is totally not related, but it worked again! (Before that, I tried to restart Xcode, restart iOS, none of them was working.)

Answer (score 0):

I just run into the same issue. And I see there is solution already but it could help others: make sure you are in the **Main.storyboard** and not in the **LaunchScreen.storyboard**

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The bug is weird. And all answers didn't help me. 
The following steps were useful for me:

- go to project file.
- Click on the button near "Launch Images Source"

After that Xcode shows assets in the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

For me the bug was caused by missing interface restoration. I think it happens when I open the project file where the Assets editor was open last time. If I close the tab which containts the Assets editor, quit Xcode then open the project again, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After trying above all tricks, I just made a copy somewhere of the file which has the issue and deleted that file from Xcode. Opened it directly from there and file seemed good. Dragging it to the project solved this heinous issue.

Answer (score 0):

none of the above answers worked for me,
what worked was, there is a filter text box in bottom right and for some reason some random text was typed in that, just clearing that text box fixed the issue.