# XCode isn't showing selection?

Tags: xcode, xcode7.1

I'm using XCode 7.1. There is no selection area for any views in the storyboard, can't change any height, width for any view?? Here is [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqsik.png) when I select the view.

How do i get that corner selection area ?

Comment: Clean project, Restart Xcode or vice-versa.

Comment: This issue is from last 10-14 days. I did this from last many days.

Comment: Tried re-installing Xcode? This is happening only to one project or to each?

Comment: For all project. and also re-installed xcode.

Comment: Happened same to me. I re-installed Xcode to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Just select a random fil in the left column then select again your storyboard file. It's working back..

See also: [XCode Interface Builder is showing "No selection" for all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373141/xcode-interface-builder-is-showing-no-selection-for-all-files)