# Turn off (Core Data) automatic codegen in Xcode 9?

Tags: core-data, xcode9

There used to be an option to turn off the automatic codegen of Core Data entities in Xcode8 but it seems to be gone in xCode 9.

Did it go somewhere else or is this option gone for good?

Comment: maybe it is still there. xCode 9.2 won't let me select it. The data model inspector is always empty no matter if I select an entitiy or not. So I guess the problem is somewhere else and the option is still there. thx anyways

Comment: Seems like this was rather a problem with the "data model inspector" not showing anything. See this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34373141/332248 Restarting xCode solved it. My bad.