# Xcode Interface builder shows "No Selection"

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode12

The interface builder is not showing any property of the controls that I select in view. It just shows a text "No selection".

I am trying on Xcode12. Is there anyone facing the same issue? The following image shows how my interface builder looks like even after selecting controls.

I tried clearing derived data, restarting XCode & restarting machine. But the issue comes back again.

Anyone who was able to solve the issue please help me.....

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode Interface Builder is showing "No selection" for all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373141/xcode-interface-builder-is-showing-no-selection-for-all-files)

Comment: Unfortunately no. @Akif